# Lazy Load the swiper slider images when it is not in viewport

Tags: slider, lazy-loading, viewport, swiper.js

I am currently using Swiper 5.3.7. Everything works fine except the Lazy Loading.
I am using a separate **Lazysizes** for Lazy Loading images in the site.
And I am aware that **Swiper slider** provides Lazy Loading only for images that are inside the slider(Active/Inactive slides).

When I am using **Lazysizes** with **Swiper's Lazy Load**, Lazy Load works perfect until I reach the viewport. Once I am in the viewport, it loads all the images of the slides irrespective of the active/inactive state(which means Swiper's lazy loading is not working when combined with Lazysizes).

**Expected Outcome:**
Swiper Lazy Load should be enabled when the page reaches the viewport. Till then Lazysizes will control the images loading.